# What's the best way to upload text from Android device to Website?

Tags: android, sql, web

I'm trying to upload a line of text every 15mins or so to be viewed on my website. I've thought about using ftp to upload a text file. I've looked at androids sql api but I didn't see a way to upload the db easily.                                  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have PHP or Java or CGI/Perl on your webserver?

Comment: I think I can use any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to upload a text file (probably works with other files) using the sample app on this site which uses FTP:
http://wiki-android.blogspot.com/2012/12/creating-android-ftp-client-ftp.html#comment-form

But the text file is created in the app and not saved. I'm trying to see if it's possible to upload a text file that already exists. When I figure it out I'll post here.

Update:
Posting to a web server is a much better approach. Something I did not know about at the time.